# Unexplained 125% zoom from browser

Tags: browser

I have a jsFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/uncjLty7/2/  - with a 100 x 100 box.  But when it runs, the width of the box on the screen is actually 125px.

[image]

It behaves as if I had the browser zoom set for 125%, but I don't. It's 100%.  The example here is with Chrome but I see the same thing with Firefox.  What is applying this zoom and how can I kill it?

Thanks for any help.

```
#box {
width:100px;  
height:100px;
background-color:red;

}
```

Comment: Which tool are you using to measure? If you inspect the div with the loup of Chrome default inpsector, is it also 125px?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you happen to be working with a 125% zoom in the OS itself?

[image]

To go there with win 7:

- right click on your destkop
- last option (customize? )
- "Display" (bottom left)

Comment: Yes!  That's it!  There must be some obscure key combination that triggers that and I typed it accidentally.  Thank You!